# Angularjs doesnt select first element

Tags: angularjs

I want to set the first element selected. I used ng-init but doesnt work. How can I solve?

HTML

```
  <select id="room" name="room" ng-init="rooms.id=1" ng-model="searchRoom" class="custom-select">
     <option value="{{rooms.id}}" ng-repeat="rooms in searchRoomValues track by $index">{{rooms.value}}</option> 
  </select>
```

Js

```
$scope.searchRoomValues=[{value: 'Not', id:1},{value: '1+0', id:1648}, {value: '1+1', id:1649}, {value: '2+1', id:1650}, {value: '3+1', id:1651}, {value: '4+1', id:1652}, {value: '5+1', id:1653}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ng-options`:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.searchRoomValues = [{
    value: 'Not',
    id: 1
  }, {
    value: '1+0',
    id: 1648
  }, {
    value: '1+1',
    id: 1649
  }, {
    value: '2+1',
    id: 1650
  }, {
    value: '3+1',
    id: 1651
  }, {
    value: '4+1',
    id: 1652
  }, {
    value: '5+1',
    id: 1653
  }];
  $scope.selected = $scope.searchRoomValues[0];
});
```

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item as item.value for item in searchRoomValues"></select>
</body>
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YaJosq6cXq8uyY6ZYGxg?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

you must initial `$scope.searchRoom` in controller

```
$scope.searchRoom=1
```

or in ng-init:

```
  <select id="room" name="room" ng-init="searchRoom=1" ng-model="searchRoom" class="custom-select">
     <option ng-value="{{rooms.id}}" ng-repeat="rooms in searchRoomValues track by $index">{{rooms.value}}</option> 
  </select>
```

Comment: In this case, the first option is the _most_ correct, and best practice. `ng-init`  is to be used very sparingly, so I would not recommend the second option.